# Alternatives to composite key in Django

Tags: python, django, database, composite-key, composite-primary-key

I'm trying to create a database for my project in Django and I read that it doesn't support composite keys. I'd like to get some alternatives, I was looking some here in StackOverflow, one of them was to create a hash of the fields value and set as your unique id; however, I believe that it would be a problem because of collisions and by the fact that information can change.

Explaining my project a bit:
- I have 3 tables (User, Site, Links)
- User (user account), Site (one user can have a list of Sites registered in his account), Links (one site can have a list of links registered in it)

The solution that I thought until now is this:

User

```
# User table
id [primary key]
first_name
last_name
email
...
```

Site

```
# Site table
id [primary key]
id_user [foreign key] (who created the site perfil)
name
root_link
```

Links

```
# Links table
id [primary key]
id_site [foreign key] (the site whose link belong)
link
status
```

If I could use composite key I would join the primary key with the foreign key, as I can't do this I'd like to know if this is a good solution or there are better ones? I'm avoiding to use alternatives that is not native from Django, but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I don't understand why you need a composite key here at all. That is a perfectly normal parent > child > grandchild relationship, with no particular complexities, and is modelled fine with the relationships you have. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I agree with @DanielRoseman. A composite key is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Meta:
    unique_together = ('fieldA', 'fieldB')
```

where fieldA and fieldB are the keys you need to be unique as a tuple